# Counting number of lines with conditions

Tags: perl

This is my script count.pl, I am trying to count the number of lines in a file.
The script's code :

```
chdir $filepath;

if (-e "$filepath"){
$total = `wc -l < file.list`;
printf "there are $total number of lines in file.list";
}
```

i can get a correct output, but i do not want to count blank lines and  anything in the file that start with `#`. any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is a Perl program already open the file and read it, filtering out lines that don't count with

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
my $num_lines = grep { not /^$|^\s*#/ } <$fh>;
```

where `$filename` is "`file.list`."  If by "blank lines" you mean also lines with spaces only then chagne regex to `/^\s*$|^\s*#/`. See [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep), and [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) for regex used in its condition.

That filehandle `$fh` gets closed when the control exits the current scope, or add `close $fh;` after the file isn't needed for processing any more. Or, wrap it in a block with [do](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do)

```
my $num_lines = do { 
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
    grep { not /^$|^\s*#/ } <$fh>; 
};
```

This makes sense doing if the sole purpose of opening that file is counting lines.

Another thing though: an operation like `chdir` should always be checked, and then there is no need for the race-sensitive `if (-e $filepath)` either. Altogether

```
# Perhaps save the old cwd first so to be able to return to it later
#my $old_cwd = Cwd::cwd;
chdir $filepath or die "Can't chdir to $filepath: $!";

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
my $num_lines = grep { not /^$|^\s*#/ } <$fh>;
```

A couple of other notes:

- There is no reason for `printf`. For all normal prints use `say`, for which you need `use feature qw(say);` at the beginning of the program. See [feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature) pragma
- Just in case, allow me to add: every program must have at the beginning

  ```
  use warnings;
  use strict;
  ```

---

Perhaps the original intent of the code in the question is to allow a program to try a non-existing location, and not die? In any case, one way to keep the `-e` test, as asked for

```
#my $old_cwd = Cwd::cwd;
chdir $filepath or warn  "Can't chdir to $filepath: $!";

my $num_lines;
if (-e $filepath) { 
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
    $num_lines = grep { not /^$|^\s*#/ } <$fh>; 
}
```

where I still added a warning if `chdir` fails. Remove that if you really don't want it.  I also added a declaration of the variable that is assigned the number of lines, with `my $total_lines;`. If it is declared earlier in your real code then of course remove that line here.

Comment: hi unfortunately, its not working. or did i do it wrongly. can you be more detailed

Comment: @WenhanXiao More detailed with what? It works fine in my tests -- how is it "not working?"  The snippet in your question presumes that there is a `$filepath` (or the program will exit) and that there is `$filename` in that path (or the program will exit).

Comment: im quite a beginner at this, and all this is actually quite messy, i'm not sure what to type , and where to type your codes. i would like to stay with the if (-e "$filepath") , changing the whole structure is changing everything i know about perl. so if by continuing from if (-e "$filepath"), what should i do?

Comment: The second snippet of posted code exactly replaces what you have in the question. The `if (-e $filepath)` is redundant (unneeded) since if `$filepath` doesn't exist then `chdir $filepath` returns false and so the program dies.  But I'll add that...

Comment: @WenhanXiao Added a complete replacement for the code in the question, with the `-e $filepath`

Comment: aite imma try it now, anyways, do you know how to run a command like u normally would in cmd, but i want to run this command in the script, after the if statement, lets say, curl " http/upload.com" upload: ( datahere)

Comment: @WenhanXiao There are many ways to run an external command out of a script -- many very good ways and some not so good :)  It's best to post that as a separate question.  (But first look for it on Stackoverflow since it's been asked and answered many many times already). In short, best use libraries, and which one to choose depends on what precisely you need.  Some to look up: `IPC::System::Simple`, `Capture::Tiny`, `IPC::Run`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233596/discussion-between-wenhan-xiao-and-zdim).

Comment: The last chunk of code replaces the code in the question, except that I used `$filename` variable for your `file.list`.  If `$filepath` doesn't exist it will now print a warning, and if `$filename` (so your `file.list`) doesn't exist it will 'die` (exit with a message).

Comment: As for the follow up question of how to run commands out of a script, here are links to some good libraries: [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple) and [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) and [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run)

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -ne '$n++ unless /^$|^#/ or eof; print "$n\n" if eof'
```

Works with multiple files too.

```
 perl -ne '$n++ unless /^$|^#/ or eof; END {print "$n\n"}'
```

Better for a single file.

```
open(my $fh, '<', $filename);
my $n = 0;
for(<$fh>) { $n++ unless /^$|^#/}
print $n;
```

Comment: hi i believe this is command? i am looking for script

Comment: @WenhanXiao they gave you the command and the script version

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` to filter out the "unwanted" lines in a single file:

```
sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' infile | wc -l
```

Obviously, you can also replace `infile` with a list of files.

Comment: $total = sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' file.list | wc -l    ......
it dosnt work tho

Comment: That is because your statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple, no any magic.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $count = 0;

while( <> ) {
    $count++ unless /^\s*$|^\s*#/;
}

say "Total $count lines";
```

Reference:
[<>](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop)